# Difference between 'Worth less' and 'Worthless?'

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Why is there a difference between `Worth less` and `Worthless`? I feel like they should mean the same thing, but they don't ironically

Comment: Why do you feel they should mean the same thing, and what research have you done to try to find the reasons for the meanings?

Comment: Can you edit your question and give a sentence for one of them? and then also give the same sentence with the other and see of they are different?

Comment: A perfect vase is valuable.  A chipped one is worth less.  A smashed one is worthless.

Comment: @Simon B A perfect vase might be priceless.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/600416/2085).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are confusing the word *[less](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/less?s=t)* with the suffix *[-less](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-less?s=t)*.

The suffix means "without":

- A *childless* couple is one without children.
- A *colorless, odorless, tasteless* liquid has no color, odor, or taste.
- A *worthless* object has no value or worth.

*Less* is usually used as an adjective or adverb and is the comparative of *little* (little, less, least):

- Six is *less* than three.
- Rayon costs *less* than silk.
- A house in the suburbs is usually worth *less* than one in the city.

Comment: I would correct your definition of  'less' meaning 'little' .. it is a comparative word associated with relative quantity not a small quantity necessarily.  Our galaxy might have less than another galaxy but both have billions of stars

Comment: I did not say _less_ means _little_, but is the comparative of _little_. Little, less, least should be uncontroversial. Compared to Jupiter, the Earth is a little planet.

Comment: @Tom22 I have little to say. He has less to say. She has the least to say of all of us.

Comment: @tchrist yes, but less doesn't tie to little directly.  Little is actually making a statement about there being "less than expected" while 'less' is only relative. "more" relates to little just as much as "less" relates to little.  I have little to say, he has more to say,  and Abe had a ton to say but while he overwhelmed me he still had less to say than that blowhard Dave.  Abe had far more than 'little'  to say. "less" in that case referred to the second highest amount of volume.

Comment: @tchrist  or the most simple "less than Mary but more than Bob"  ... less makes no statement whatsoever assuming that any of the trio had small quantities or large quantities compared to normal expectations.

Comment: @Tom22 It most certainly does so. The very first sense given by the OED for *less* reads: “A. *adj.* (and *n.*) Used as the comparative of **little** *adj., pron., n.,* and *adv.*”  In an identical fashion the very first sense given by the OED for *least* reads: “Used as the superlative of **little** *adj., pron., n.,* and *adv.*” It’s clear that **the comparative degree of *little* is *less* and the superlative degree is *least*.** How much clearer a “tie” would you ask for than this? English has worked this way since we only used 3 digits for years.

Comment: @tchrist  I'm not disputing that it ~can~ relate to little however that is far from it's only meaning and not IMO it's primary meaning https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/less  A smaller amount of; not as much.  as determiner ‘the less time spent there, the better’
as pronoun ‘storage is less of a problem than it used to be’  - 
‘they returned in less than an hour’
1.1 Fewer in number.  Certainly "fewer" isn't little (as I used less to refer to relative billions) .. or Warren Buffet is worth less than Bill Gates(Buffet is number 2 out of 340 millions americans though)

Comment: @Tom22 You challenged Karl's characterization of *less* being the comparative of *little*. Karl was completely correct in his morphology — *little, less, least* — and there is nothing to dispute here.

Comment: That the comparative can be used in contexts where the things compared do not have the quality described by the positive lies in the nature of  comparison itself. Houston has a smaller population than Chicago, but neither have small populations. _Smaller_ still remains the comparative of the positive _small_.

Answer (score 0):

worth less =  less valuable

worthless = pointless, senseless or not valuable

Comment: I understand, but I'm more curious as to why there is a difference. I know what the difference is. But I just feel like it is a little funny that they sound so similar but are different. I was just wondering if there was any reason for that.

Comment: If I were to get snarky about it, I would say you have a 'senseless' question. ;)  I'm having fun there, but the form of putting 'less' at the end of words means 'without' .... 'baseless' , 'endless' etc.  Using two words uses the stand alone meaning of less .. as the opposite of 'more'  ... no less than that.

Answer (score 0):

Worth less means diminished in value but worthless means of no value at all.